# Cant Access Registry even with Elevated Permission

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, permissions, registry

I am making a Service Program where it will change the start up type of certain service. 
My Current code does not even let me open the registry for writing, even when I "Run As Admin".

Code:

```
ServiceKey = Registry.LocalMachine;
ServiceKey = ServiceKey.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\" + ServiceName, true);
ServiceKey.SetValue("Start", 2, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```

However, I get this error: Requested Registry Access is not allowed.
Anyone know a solution ?

(PS. I know there are other way's I could be doing this, but it's bother me how It's not letting me Access the registry.) My program is also running as Any CPU.

Comment: Found the problem, on some registry, if you check the "Permission", you will notice that not even an admin has the permission to change the registry. You can change the permission your self but on my case, I will find a different approach to editing the service start up.

Comment: Hi, can you add your solution as an answer and then tick it to accept it please? This will mark the question as solved, so others won't look at it to try to help, but also people with the same problem will find your solution easier. (It's ok to answer your own question!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem, on some registry, if you check the "Permission", you will notice that not even an admin has the permission to change the registry. You can change the permission your self but on my case, I will find a different approach to editing the service start up.

Answer (score 3):

The way to change a service's configuration is not to whack the registry. You use the service control manager. MSDN even has [a sample program](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682006%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that changes a service's start type. I found this page by going to [About Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681921%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), then clicking [Service Configuration Programs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685147%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), then [Service Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685146%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: yea, thats what i did ultimately.